# Rest get and post methods returns 404 error

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I have the following code (coded by someone else) with various Rest annotations:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.messenger.resource;

import java.util.List;
// removed most of import.javax..... imports, to avoid error: it looks like mostly code


import org.koushik.javabrains.messenger.model.Message;
import org.koushik.javabrains.messenger.service.MessageService;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }
}
```

I am using the postman rest client, and I am getting the `404` response when using all the three methods on `http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages`.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.koushik.javabrains.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: suppose you are using Jersey 2 and it would be helpful if you can share the jersey configuration on `web.xml`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu: I am using 2.16. And I have added web.xml.

Comment: Check my simple project :
https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/RESTful-WS-Messenger-CRUD-

Comment: Shouldn't your servlet mapping be `<url-pattern>messenger/*</url-pattern>` instead of  `<url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>` ?

Comment: @Suresh makes no difference. still getting the same error.

Comment: @CoderACJHP: Using your project I am getting the same 404 error.